# lucene analyzer for multi values in one field

Tags: lucene

I've indexed document having title field with values like:

```
title one; second hand; third bird
```

So my document has 3 titles:

- title one
- second hand
- third bird

Twis document should be found for following example queries:

- title one
- hand
- bird
- third

But It can't be found when user types:

- title bird
- second one
- third title

As I previously mentioned, all titles are stored in one database field:

> "title one; second hand; third bird"

What kind of analyzer can I use to make it work as I described?
I've written simple SemicolonTokenizer extending CharTokenizer - but that is not enough, because the database is huge and I can not use * in the query

Any advice would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

A simple `LetterTokenizer` or `StandardTokenizer` should do fine (or perhaps more to the point `StandardAnalyzer` or `SimpleAnalyzer`).

I don't know anything about your Semicolon Tokenizer, so don't know if that is causing problems for you, but based on what you say about the searches that DO work, this may not be the case.

Are the queries passed from the user quoted, or passed in as a PhraseQuery?  If so, that is probably the source of your problem.  A quoted query, like:

```
content:"title hand"
```

Will be sensitive to order, and so would not be found in your example.  However, you would be able to find either:

```
content:title content:hand
```

Or

```
content:(title hand)
```

And, for more on the [Lucene Query Parser Synax](http://lucene.apache.org/core/old_versioned_docs/versions/2_9_1/queryparsersyntax.html).

Comment: I have field and multiple values. So, how can I build a query like `field:(value1 value2)` using Apache's Lucene 8 API

Comment: @AMagic - That's... still valid queryparser syntax: http://lucene.apache.org/core/8_0_0/queryparser/org/apache/lucene/queryparser/classic/package-summary.html#Field_Grouping

Answer (score 0):

the point is that my current search works for:

```
content:(title hand)
```

and it should not return results, because title is: "title one" and "second hand". There is no title "title hand"